# Создание Roster в Smack

Tags: java, android, xmpp

Как правильно создать `roster` в `Smack`? Я получаю `SmackExceptionNotLoggedunException Client is not logged in`, при попытке создать новый `roster`.

Мой код:

```
Roster roster = Roster.getInstanceFor(connection);
```

Дальше:

```
 roster.createEntry(jid, name, groups);
```

В моем случае это:

```
 String [] groups ={"TestGroup"};
                try {
                    roster.createEntry("test2@irynas-macbook-air.local/Irynas-MacBook-Air", "test2@irynas-macbook-air.local", groups);
                } catch (SmackException.NotLoggedInException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SmackException.NoResponseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (XMPPException.XMPPErrorException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Первый параметр `jid` - это `id` пользователя, который создает `roster`? `name` - это название roster или пользователя? Где брать `groups`? я создала просто массив строк, не знаю правильно ли это, может нужно как-то по другому создавать?

Comment: Вы ведь `connect` у `connection` точно вызывали?

Comment: @Suvitruf да,  connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(configBuilder.build());

Comment: Я про `connection.login(...)` или `connection.connect(...)`.

Comment: @Suvitruf  connection.connect(); connection.login(); - есть

Answer (score 0):

Это рабочий код, состоящий из объявленных переменных и трёх методов

1) Объявляем переменные:

```
private XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder builder;
private AbstractXMPPConnection connection;
private Roster roster;
```

2) Метод для получения Билдера:

```
private XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder getBuilder(String user, String password) {

        if (builder == null) {
            builder = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
            builder.setUsernameAndPassword(user, password);
            builder.setServiceName("irynas-macbook-air.local");
            builder.setHost("irynas-macbook-air.local");
            builder.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
            builder.setResource("Irynas-MacBook-Air");
            builder.setPort(5222);
        }
        return builder;
    }
```

3)  Метод для получения соединения с авторизацией:

```
 public AbstractXMPPConnection getConnection(@NonNull String user, @NonNull String password) {
        if (connection == null) {
            connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(getBuilder(user, password).build());
            connection.addConnectionListener(new ConnectionListener() {
                @Override
                public void connected(XMPPConnection connection) {
                    Log.d("Custom", "ChatSystem.class -> connectionListener -> connected! " + connection.getHost());
                }

                @Override
                public void authenticated(XMPPConnection connection, boolean resumed) {
                    Log.d("Custom", "ChatSystem.class -> connectionListener -> authenticated");
                }

                @Override
                public void connectionClosed() {
                    Log.d("Custom", "ChatSystem.class -> connectionListener -> connectionClosed ");
                }

                @Override
                public void connectionClosedOnError(Exception e) {
                    Log.d("Custom", "ChatSystem.class -> connectionListener -> connectionClosedOnError");
                }

                @Override
                public void reconnectionSuccessful() {
                    Log.d("Custom", "ChatSystem.class -> connectionListener -> reconnectionSuccessful");
                }

                @Override
                public void reconnectingIn(int seconds) {
                    Log.d("Custom", "ChatSystem.class -> connectionListener -> reconnectingIn");
                }

                @Override
                public void reconnectionFailed(Exception e) {
                    Log.d("Custom", "ChatSystem.class -> connectionListener -> reconnectionFailed");
                }
            });

            Roster.setDefaultSubscriptionMode(Roster.SubscriptionMode.accept_all);
            roster = Roster.getInstanceFor(connection);
            roster.setRosterLoadedAtLogin(true);
            roster.addRosterListener(this);
            roster.addRosterLoadedListener(this);
        }

        return connection;
    }
```

4) Метод для получения списка пользователей (ростера):

```
public Roster getRoster() {
        if (connection == null || roster == null) {
            return null;
        }
        roster = Roster.getInstanceFor(connection);
        return roster;
    }
```

Надеюсь, это поможет вам. Удачи!

Comment: так в вашем примере нет создания нового roster, есть только получение уже существующего roster.